# Why does changing my variable value not effect my list?

Tags: python

I don't understand why my list doesn't change the variables value:

```
b = 3
a = [1, 2, b]
b = 10
print(a)
```

The value for b is still 3 as I print it. Why is it not 10?

Comment: When you do `b = 10` you don't change the value of `b` you change what b points to. Also int are inmutable, so you cannot change them

Comment: In the assignment to `a`, `b` is evaluated as an expression.  It doesn't create a perpetual reference to it.  It evaluates it, captures the value, and uses that to initialize the list.  It would be no different if you assigned `b` directly to `a`.  You wouldn't expect `a` to change after another assignment to `b`, right?  Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To gain a deep understanding of this you really have to learn C the programming language that created python and how pointers work.

The first thing to note is that if you write:

```
b = <stuff>
a = [1,2,b]
b = <other thing>
```

Then no matter what, the variable "b" has been re-purposed. Whatever you put in "a" stays in "a", at the time "a" was created. "b" is then changed to another value. Python used "b" to make "a", but python doesn't keep track that the variable "b" was used, it only keeps the value that "b" had to make "a".

Now if "b" was something mutable (something we could update in memory without creating a copy) and instead of overwriting "b" we mutated "b". Then "a" would receive that mutation of "b"; because "a" would be storing the address to "b" and not a copy of "b". For example,

```
b = [1,2,3]
a = [1,2,b]
print(a)
b.append(4)
print(a)
```

This happens because "b" was not an immutable integer (can only be copied), but was instead a mutable list (can be updated in memory without copying it). We then operated on "b" with a .append() that doesn't copy the list. This means that the memory address that "a" received has been updated and when you look in "a" it returns what is currently at the memory address.

If you want to check if python variables have the same memory address or not, then use python's "is" builtin. For example,

```
17 is 16+1
[1,2,3] is [1,2,3]
```

This shows that python only has one 17 in memory (at all times, there is only ever one 17) and both the 17 and 16+1 pointed to that same memory integer, an immutable integer that exists in memory only once. However, the two lists created (even though they look the same and have the same numbers) were written to two different memory addresses.